# Enable/disable button with Javascript+Struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am working on a Struts2 Java application and in a jquery grid (in a jsp), i have (in the header part of the grid) a button to export the results displayed by the grid into an excel file.
So i added this button using a script in my JSP. So what i need is to disable the button and re enable it when the struts action is done.
How would you guys do that ??
Here is the code i used to add the button (thanks for reminding me this :D)

```
    var $btnExcel = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel');
    if(!$btnExcel.length) {
        var $a = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > a');
        var $newA = $a.clone();

        $newA.attr('style', 'right: 25px; padding-top: 2px;');
        $newA.attr('id', 'btnExcel');
        $newA.children("span").remove();
        $newA.append($('<input id="searchForm_exportExcel" type="image" onclick="exportExcelFunc();" src="/project/img/page_white_excel.png" title="<s:text name="project.message.js.button.excelExtraction"/>"/>'));
        $newA.insertAfter($a);
    }
}

// export excel
function exportExcelFunc() {  
    $("#searchForm").attr("action", "exportExcel.action");
    $("#searchForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, without any code it will be hard to help you ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot to add it !thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your must submit your form in AJAX to get a response.
Just before submitting, set your button disabled.
After getting the response enbable your button.

This is something like this :

```
var formData = $("#myForm").serialize(); //get all data from form

//disable button
 $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel').prop('disabled', true);

//do the POST thingies
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "url_to_your_struts2_action",
     cache: false,
     data: formData,
     success: function(response){
        //do some success stuff...
        //enable button
        $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel').prop('disabled', false);
     },
     error: function(error){
        //do some errorstuff...
        //enable button
        $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel').prop('disabled', false);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when using this i did not have any file downloaded .. maybe this was caused by the fact that i had no response using this ??